# Delete registry keys on Windows CE 5.0

Tags: c#, registry, windows-ce

Using Visual Studio 2005 and C# (CF v2.0). The following code deletes a registry key fine on Windows CE 6.0:

```
RegistryKey key_test = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Test");
RegistryKey key_users = key_test.CreateSubKey("Users");
key_users.DeleteSubKey("User1");  // Yes, this key does exist!
key_users.Flush();
// Now power down the device; on power up, key is gone
```

But exactly the same code fails to delete the key on Windows CE 5.0. After calling "DeleteSubKey" and then checking the registry manually, the key appears to have disappeared. But when you power the device back up...the key has returned!

I can detect the operating system, so I then tried a variation for Windows CE 5.0:

```
key_users.DeleteSubKeyTree("User1");    // DeleteSubKey also fails
key_users.Close();
```

but this also failed to delete the key. Again, the key appears to go but after powering the device back up, the key is back. I've encapsulated the above code in try-catch blocks and no exceptions are raised, the code runs ok, just doesn't work. Any ideas? Do I need to do something extra on Windows CE 5.0 that I am missing? Adding keys is no problem, a simple "Flush" adds the key.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your ce5 device does not have permanent registry. Did you try to create a key? It is still there after a reboot?

Comment: No, the registry is permanent. As stated in the final line, adding a key works. Curiously, if I use a 3rd party registry editor or the in-built Visual Studio "Remote Registry Editor", then both appear to delete the key successfully...but on power cycle, the key is back! Finally, I manually deleted the key, but this time I didn't power down, but use the Start > Suspend command, and this time the key was deleted.

Comment: In this case a flush may solve the issue and it seems that there is one in your code. suspend will force a flush of the whole filesystem, and this may explain the different behaviour. Adding a key would likely increase the size of the hive file, while deleting it may not. Do you have caching enabled on the storage used to save the registry? Maybe there is something wrong there.

Comment: How do I check if caching is enabled on the storage? The CE 5.0 and CE 6.0 devices both come from the same supplier (in Germany). As far as I know, the devices (and their associated storage) are configured similarly, just the newer CE 6.0 device has a faster processor, more memory...and runs CE 6.0 instead of CE 5.0!

Comment: Can you try to call the RegFlushKey API trough PInvoke? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891455.aspx
This can be useful to understand if the .flush function in .NET has some issues.

Comment: Will try that now and report back. Note that I was able to solve the issue by forcing a suspend and reboot of the device using the following code, but its a little ugly from the users' perspective.

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern int SetSystemPowerState(string psState, int nStateFlags, int nOptions);

    // Reboot device
    SetSystemPowerState(null, POWER_STATE_RESET, 0);

Comment: That works, thanks! Possibly a limitation of the .NET Compact Framework or something to do with caching on the storage device? I used the following code, deleted the user and then powered down the device about 1s later. On power up, the user was gone:

`// Pinvoke
public const UInt32 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002;
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern int RegFlushKey(IntPtr hKey);

// Delete key
key_users.DeleteSubKey("User1");

// Flush registry
IntPtr hkLM = new IntPtr(unchecked((int)frmCommon.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE));
RegFlushKey(hkLM);`